Using multiple text inputs for one output with RoBERTa/DistillBERT
In a current project i want to fine tune a RoBERTa/DistillBERT for text classification.
The model should take two text input features, limited to the length of around 280 characters, and generate a single output label.
However, using the provided base models by Huggingface, they seem to only accept a single text input feature.
I found this paper and this forum post, suggesting to concatenate the inputs and separate them by using a special token.
However, i wonder if there are better approaches, which do not use concatination, but instead keep the input features separated.
